# Is there a way to force/manage file locking in windows?

Tags: windows, file-sharing, windows-networking

I have a 2 Windows machines networked and I am having trouble with simultaneous access to files. I would like only one user to be able to open a file at a time, which I thought was automatic, using [file locks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking).... if the program used to access the file is locking the file.

I believe the problem I am having is some of the programs I use, don't lock the file, and there for can be modified simultaneously by multiple users, which is very much **not** desired.

Currently I am having this problem with only two computers, although as soon as I can figure out a solution to this problem the network is going to be expanded to 6 computers, which will include Windows 7, Vista, and XP, as well as a central file server (Samba).

Is there a way to ensure that all files opened in windows get locked? I have considered some sort of version control system, but all of the ones I have looked at are way too complicated.  All I need is to ensure that multiple users can't write to a file at the same time.

Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

The suggestions are appreciated, although here are some guidelines I was hoping to fulfill.

- There is a large number of files and directories that are going to be shared, which will be served by a Samba file server. So managing share access with windows sharing won't be possible.
- Multiple people need to be able to access a given folder simultaneously.
- Samba supports file locking, so ideally I would like to force windows to place locks on files, even when the program being used normally wouldn't do so. (Is there a program that can do this?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a shared folder and allow only one connection

[image]

Comment: This does not apply to a samba server. It anyway allows only one user on the *whole share*.

Answer (score 0):

The most office files accept modifying on network. You should look at share options. For exe files and folders there are no simple ways. You could organize user files in folders visible only for owner+admin there is well knowm microsoft utility to hide/unhide folders in xp/2003? Other way is organize libraries in 7 for users may it help?

Comment: UNLOCKER doesn't seem to help me to *lock* anything, although I am sure it will be helpful once I get the file locks working. I don't need to lock any .exe files or folders.  The share options is a good idea, but unfortunately that won't work once I start using the file server.  Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a samba server, you could try to set the share to `strict locking`.

This option denies access to an entire file if any byte-range lock exists in it.

For more info see [Using Samba : Locks and Oplocks](http://oreilly.com/openbook/samba/book/ch05_05.html).

Comment: Thanks, although that doesn't seem to have any effect on the programs that don't use file locks

Comment: Which programs don't use file locks?

Comment: We use a CAD/CAM program called Vector, that doesn't seem to use them.